# Why kubernetes use protobuf format in etcd and not spilt up to many key-value pairs?

Tags: database, kubernetes, etcd

I noticed that kubernetes apiserver marshals the whole CRD object to protobuf format, and store it to etcd.

I have some questions below:

1. May be a CRD can have many fields(such as two millions fields?), the marshalled protobuf may very big. And we all know it etcd is designed for handling small key value pairs typical for metadata, is this a good idea to store a big marshalled protobuf?
2. Etcd is designed for small key pairs, why k8s not spilt CRD object to many key-value and store to etcd?
3. Etcd has default 2GB storage quota, 8GB is a suggested maximum size. If all marshalled protobuf is very big, how etcd will be ?

Well, the root of this discussion is because I'm using etcd for a CMDB project, and currently referencing the design of k8s. Since each device may have hundreds of thousands of routes to store, I'm worried that etcd will soon became a bottleneck and I don't know weather to spilt it up or store it in one key-value pair.

And, currently there may no database that support watchers and revision like etcd.

Comment: The higher-level answer to this is that it's not a good idea to have a very large custom resource.  If you need storage with millions of fields, provisioning your own database via a StatefulSet will probably be a better storage mechanism than trying to use the Kubernetes API server.  (Consider that there's a 1 MB limit on ConfigMap data, and a dedicated user looking at the API documentation could in principle hand-write most Kubernetes objects; what you're describing seems very different from this.)

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks. It looks like that etcd is not a best selection for my usage, there are some limits for k8s but I don't know.